# How to make shorter an sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Am getting Total Count Of Following Details From Table

```
TODAYS Inquiry
TODAYS Leads
TODAYS Quotation
TODAYS Quotation Amount
TODAYS Closed inquiry
TODAYS Payment Amount
```

So for that I am using Following Query

```
<?php
  $today1 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS todayinq FROM `register` WHERE DATE(`ipdatee`) = CURDATE()";
  $today2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS todaylead FROM `register` WHERE data_status = 2 AND DATE(`ipdatee`) = CURDATE()";
  $today3 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS todayqamt FROM `register` WHERE `q_total_amount` > 0 AND DATE(`ipdatee`) = CURDATE()";
  $today4 = "SELECT SUM(q_total_amount) AS todayqamt2 FROM `register` 
             WHERE `q_total_amount` > 0 AND DATE(`ipdatee`) = CURDATE()";
  $today5 = "SELECT SUM(lead_payment_amount) AS todaypamt FROM `register` 
             WHERE `lead_payment_amount` > 0 AND DATE(`ipdatee`) = CURDATE()";
?>
```

And Same thing i Am doing for Weekly And Monthly So This code repeted X3 Times. So my question is does it make sense to use by this type or have any way to shorter an query ?

Comment: You are using different conditions for different query , so cant merge in single query

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in one query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS todayinq,
       SUM( (data_status = 2) ) as todaylead,
       SUM( (q_total_amount > 0) ) as todayqamt,
       SUM( GREATEST(q_total_amount, 0) ) as totalqamt,
       SUM( GREATEST(lead_payment_amount, 0) ) as todaypamt
FROM register r
WHERE ipdatee >= CURDATE() AND ipdatee < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Note the `WHERE` clause.  By removing the `DATE()` function, the optimizer can make use of an index on `ipdatee`, if one exists.

This query uses the MySQL feature that booleans are treated as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So,

```
SUM( (data_status = 2) )
```

is the same as:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN data_status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Usually, I prefer standard SQL when it is available.  This happens to be one database-specific convention that I actually like, probably because C was one of the first languages that I learned (and it follows the same convention).

Comment: He is using different conditions for different query

Comment: SUM( (data_status = 2) ) as todaylead, In this `data_status = 2` Can Work ? Means Given Condition Work ?

Comment: Yes @MadCoder SUM can use a SQL expression -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum .. All aggregate functions can use a SQL expression like that by the way.

Comment: `SUM( (data_status = 2) ) as todaylead,` AND `SUM( (q_total_amount > 0) ) as todayqamt,` Not Ned Sum And I tried To Put COUNT so it not giving valid result

Comment: @MadCoder . . . The logic is `SUM()`, not `COUNT()`.

Comment: Thankyouh But I need CoUNT  For above two statement Not SUM()

Comment: @MadCoder . . . This is producing the five values that you specified in your question.